# Who built the hall in reality?

Tags: meaning

I am reading [this piece](http://www.nachrichtenleicht.de/konzert-saal-eroeffnet.2045.de.html?dram:article_id=380837) of easy news but get confused by the following two sentences:

> Der berühmte Pianist Daniel Barenboim hat den Saal bauen lassen.

From the above sentence I learned that it was Daniel Barenboim who built the hall. Daniel is a pianist and conductor, not an architect, and hence he can only fund the hall, which conflicts with the meaning of the sentence. From other sources I've not got a clue whether or not he funded the hall.

> Ein berühmter Architekt aus dem Land USA, Frank Gehry, hat ihn gebaut.

And by the above text I know that the architect is Frank Gehry. And then my question is what is the role of Daniel Barenboim?

Comment: "etwas bauen lassen" = "to have sth built". Barenboim *had* the hall built. He was the principal or sponsor. He did not build the hall, (er hat den Saal nicht gebaut), he *had* it built (er hat ihn bauen **lassen**). "Lassen" is related to the english "to let", but not entirely the same.

Comment: Regardless of translation issues, "Daniel Barenboim built the hall" is a perfectly reasonable sentence in English. No single person could build a hall on their own, so it's obvious that the sentence doesn't mean that he literally laid the brick; rather, it would be understood that he was responsible for building the hall and other people did the literal building.

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I just had the impression that Lemer had overlooked the word "lassen", which changes the meaning of the sentence a bit.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis My German isn't nearly good enough to tell; I was just commenting that the presented English sentence (fragment) "Barenboim built the hall" doesn't imply what the asker seems to think it does. But your suggestion of "Barenboim had the hall built" is more explicit and much clearer way of saying it.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, please do not answer in comments. It is especially unfortunate when the answers are as good as yours (although I am not sure how much it would have added to the existing ones).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, naturally it was neither the pianist nor the architect who *built* the hall; it was the construction workers. But that issue aside, let’s address how you can tell that from the sentences.

The key word in your first example is the auxiliary verb *(jemanden etwas tun) lassen.* It can mean a number of things such as *to allow someone to do something* or *to make someone do something.* Here, it signifies that Barenboim was the brain behind the idea and that he spent the money, decided on the design and/or was the driving force behind the scenes.

The architect probably didn’t build the hall (see above) — he only drew the plans and maybe advised the construction workers on how to do it. We cannot use the *lassen* construction here, because the architect’s role is more of a recipient and transmitter of orders — and because his role in drawing is much more active than just being the funding person in the background. However, I would prefer a different full verb, for example *konstruieren* rather than *bauen.*

Comment: @Lerner Note that: the suggestion of Jan, *konstruieren* instead of *bauen* should also be used with *lassen*.

Comment: @AdInfinitum »Der Architekt hat den Konzertsaal konstruieren lassen«? Was wäre dann ein gutes Verb für die aktive Handlung des Architekten?

Comment: @Jan Sorry, es gibt zwei Bedeutungen von "Konstruieren", wenn ich in einem Wörterbuch nachschlage. Die erste ist auch "bauen" und die zweite "Entwerfen". Ich dachte du hast "bauen" gemeint.

Comment: @AdInfinitum Ah, ich hab schon gedacht, ich verwende seit ewigen Zeiten ein Wort falsch. Schön, dass sich das geklärt hat ^^

Comment: @Jan Klar hat der Architekt den Saal gebaut. Dass die Bauarbeiter ihn auch gebaut haben ändert daran doch nichts.

Comment: @sgf Der Architekt »baut« ihn in der Regel ganz genau so wie der Auftraggeber (hier: ein Pianist; in der anderen Antwort z.B. auch der König). Mir wäre nicht bekannt, dass ein Teil des Architektenstudiums beinhaltet, Steine auf einer Baustelle zu schleppen.

Comment: @Jan Und nachdem man üblicherweise sagt, dass ein Architekt ein Gebäude baut, dürfte "bauen" also nicht nur Steineschleppen bedeuten.

Answer (score 18):

The important word here is the "lassen" at the end of the sentence.

- Der berühmte Pianist Daniel Barenboim hat den Saal **gebaut**. = He has built the hall.
- Der berühmte Pianist Daniel Barenboim hat den Saal **bauen lassen**. = He has arranged the hall to be built (and most likely funded it, but that doesn't have to be the case).

So he was the guy who gave the order to build the hall (either because he funded it directly or because he could convince other people to do so based on his reputation). Frank Gehry then executed this order.

And in reality, the hall was built by a lot of anonymous workers. ;)

Comment: Danke dir auch.

Answer (score 6):

You have to understand this as follows:

> Der berühmte Pianist Daniel Barenboim **hat** den Saal *bauen*
>   **lassen**.

---

> Er **hat** den Saal **gebaut**.

He has built the hall himself.

> Er **hat** den Saal *bauen* **lassen**.

He has had the hall built (he has not built it himself).

The construction *verb + lassen* is the English counterpart of the *causative have*.

Answer (score 5):

Grundsätzlich ist der Gedanke schon richtig, dass ein Musiker wie Barenboim einen Saal eher bauen **lassen** wird als ihn selbst zu bauen. (Siehe die anderen Antworten auf diese Frage.)

Jedoch könnte man hinzuzufügen, dass je nach Kontext ein Satz wie

> Martin Müller hat den Saal gebaut

auch akzeptabel sein kann, selbst wenn Martin Müller kein Handwerker, kein Baumeister, kein Architekt, sondern 'ledglich' der Bauherr oder Financier ist. Denn man sagt ja (in weniger förmlicher Umgebung) gerne

> König Ludwig hat Schloss Neuschwanstein gebaut, und Süleyman der Prächtige hat die Süleymaniye-Moschee gebaut.

und kaum ein Leser oder Hörer wird dabei die beiden Monarchen Steine schleppen sehen. Man sagt auch

> Die katholische Kirche hat viele Pfarrhäuser gebaut

und ist sich gleichwohl bewusst, dass die Kirche dabei doch überwiegend nur den Rubel rollen lassen hat.

Möglicherweise ist die Sensibilität für solche Fragen mit Brechts "Fragen eines lesenden Arbeiters" (1935) populär geworden:

> Wer baute das siebentorige Theben?
>   In den Büchern stehen die Namen von Königen.
>   Haben die Könige die Felsbrocken herbeigeschleppt?
>   Und das mehrmals zerstörte Babylon - 
>   Wer baute es so viele Male auf? In welchen Häusern 
>  
>   Des goldstrahlenden Lima wohnten die Bauleute?
>   Wohin gingen an dem Abend, wo die Chinesische Mauer fertig war
>   Die Maurer? Das große Rom 
>   Ist voll von Triumphbögen. Wer errichtete sie? Über wen
>   triumphierten die Cäsaren? Hatte das vielbesungene Byzanz
>   Nur Paläste für seine Bewohner? Selbst in dem sagenhaften Atlantis
>   Brüllten in der Nacht, wo das Meer es verschlang
>   Die Ersaufenden nach ihren Sklaven.
>   Der junge Alexander eroberte Indien.
>   Er allein?
>   Cäsar schlug die Gallier.
>   Hatte er nicht wenigstens einen Koch bei sich?
>   Philipp von Spanien weinte, als seine Flotte
>   Untergegangen war. Weinte sonst niemand?
>   Friedrich der Zweite siegte im Siebenjährigen Krieg. Wer
>   Siegte außer ihm?
>   Jede Seite ein Sieg.
>   Wer kochte den Siegesschmaus?
>   Alle zehn Jahre ein großer Mann.
>   Wer bezahlte die Spesen?
>   So viele Berichte.
>   So viele Fragen.

Und in der Tat: Brecht hätte sich kaum zu diesem Gedicht provoziert gefühlt, wenn Aussagen wie '*Alexander der Große eroberte Indien*' nicht gang und gäbe (gewesen) wären. Insofern hat auch '*Barenboim hat einen Konzertsaal gebaut*' noch eine gewisse Gangundgäbigkeit.

Comment: Schönes Zitat und noch schöner: die _Gangundgäbigkeit_ ...

Answer (score 2):

I also think it is worth mentioning that because of the sentence structure and delivery it is implied that there are more variables to the story. These unknown variables could be anything from the land being his, his funds, his name as principle commissioner, his agreed upon commitment to conduct and/or play at the hall... either way the sentence tells you that the building of the hall was "dependent" on his approval.

Hope that helps.